# Completely replace rdoc by yard for gem install/server

Tags: rubygems, rdoc, yard

is there a way to completely replace rdoc by yard, even when installing a gem?

As it is now, `gem server` has only access to rdoc-generated docs. In some cases like the FFI-gem, the documentation is written with yard, trying to read the rdoc-generated documentation through `gem server` is quiet a pain.

So is there any possibility to replace the rdoc with yard

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yardoc/wT593X7PQjA ?

Comment: Nope, that is about switching from RDoc to Yard in a single project, but I want to replace RDoc completely by yard, so that `gem` uses yard for all documentation related tasks.